# ios Trying to drag a image left and right

Tags: ios

I have a game that has a row of cards drawn at the bottom of the screen.  I would like it so if the user touches the screen and moves his hand right, the cards will move right until he lifts his hand. Then if he moves his hand left on the touch screen, the card will move left until he lifts his hand.

My first thought was to use the swipe events.  But a swipe will not give a message until the finger is release, I want the cards to move while the hand is moving and touching the screen.

My idea was to get the x coordinate of the touch position and if it is bigger than the previous x, move the cards left, else move them right.

I started out with this block of code, but sort of stuck on what to do next, or maybe I'm doing this all wrong

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSUInteger touchCount = [touches count];
    NSUInteger tapCount = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me Ted, have you tested it? - what exactly is it you are stuck with?

Comment: trying is not a real question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some of the other touch delegate methods

Implement `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and inside that method get the initial x and y co-ordinates of the touch. Save them in to class wide instance variables.

Then in touches moved, compare the x co-ordinates of the new touch with the original co-ordinates from touches began, if x < then move left, else if x > then move right.

Note that `touchesMoved:withEvent` only gets called when the touch is moving, so if the user touches and moves to the right, then leaves their finger static, it wont report touches.

You'll need to implement `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `-touchesCancelled:withEvent:` to pick up when the touch ends.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for taking the time to answer my quastion, one problem, I can get the touchCount and Tap count but....do not know how to get the x,y position of touch event

Comment: `CGPoint touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];`